# Numbers replace themselves after pressing a button in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to make a calculator app in vb.net and I coded so it places a number in the textbox above but when I press another number the previous one disappears. I am attaching a screenshot of the app and code.

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        Label4.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Visible = True
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        Label4.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Label1.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = True
        Label3.Visible = False
        Label4.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        Label1.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = True
        Label4.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
        Label1.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = False
        Label3.Visible = False
        Label4.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = Val(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        TextBox1.Text = Val(2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to have the textbox equal itself AND add the new value to the end. So: `TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Val(1)`

Comment: VBA is not VB Net so you are asking in the wrong forum.  Please edit your tags to move the question to the correct forum.

Comment: Oh yes, if it's VB.NET then just add a + sign before the equals instead of my first comment. So: `TextBox1.Text += Val(1)`

Comment: @freeflow StackOverflow is not a forum, and tagging a question does not move it anywhere.

Comment: @Gserg  Semantics

Comment: @freeflow [Not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/147640).

Comment: @Gserg  I read that.  the bit about "." You'll be lucky if you get a relevant response. By contrast, on Stack Exchange you'd get practical responses that are 100% relevant to your question." really cracked me up.  The fact that SO imposes a structure on a topic doesn't stop it being a forum.

Comment: @Buba The `.Text` property is a string, so you need to append the string representation of the digit you're adding: `tbNumEntry.Text &= "5"`, and so on. It would be better to give the controls meaningful names - it's already got Button5 for the digit 2, so you can imagine how confusing it might end up being.

Comment: With the code as is, the only numbers/text that will appear in TextBox1 is "1" or "2" depending on whether Button2 or Button5 is clicked. Note that the Val function operates on a string, so providing a numeric value makes its use redundant as is. To grow the number in TextBox1 with each click then the implementation for each button should be: TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text & "1") 'Button1_Click TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text & "2") 'Button2_Click, etc. with buttons named so that they make sense Val isn't necessary, but will remove spaces or return 0 if a non numeric value is typed.

Answer (score 1):

See comments.
But the short answer is that in the code provided, TextBox1.Text is being replaced with a single numeric value depending on the keypad button clicked.
On each click, the additional number actually needs to be appended to whatever is currently in the textbox.
eg. for Button2_Click:

```
Dim btn as Button = CType(sender, Button)
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & btn.Text
```

Also, since this code will work for each of the numeric keypad buttons, a single handler (any suitable name) can be used:

```
Private Sub NumberPad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, etc.
```